# rspec render_template error rendering with <[]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

I have the following rspec test

```
context 'copy' do
  let(:path) { '/sales_orders/copy' }
  let(:params) { { id: sales_order.id } }

  it 'copies passed in sales_order attrs' do
    post path, params: params
    expect(subject).to render_template('sales_orders/new')
    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  end
end
```

and the following in my routes

```
resources :sales_orders, except: %i[destroy]
```

The error is the following:

```
Failures:

  1) SalesOrdersController copy copies passed in sales_order attrs
     Failure/Error: expect(subject).to render_template('sales_orders/new')
       expecting <"sales_orders/new"> but rendering with <[]>
     # ./spec/requests/sales_order_spec.rb:435:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1 minute 0.96 seconds (files took 4.35 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

Answer (score 0):

`resources :sales_orders` only includes the standard routes (which you can find [in the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)). However `copy` isn't a standard route. You can add that route and controller action like this:

```rb
# config/routes.rb

resources :sales_orders, except: %i[destroy] do
  post :copy, on: :member
end
```

```rb
# app/controllers/sales_orders_controller.rb

class SalesOrdersController < ApplicationController
  def copy
    # ...
  end
end
```

Also it looks like this action isn't doing anything, but it's just rendering a new form. In that case you might want to consider a `GET` request instead of `POST`.

Comment: I have `get 'sales_orders/copy', to: 'sales_orders#copy', as: 'copy_sales_orders'` amd `get 'sales_orders/:id/copy', to: 'sales_orders#copy', as: 'copy_sales_order'` in the routes getting the same error